# Distribute free iPhone app with hardware to customer without AppStore

Tags: iphone, licensing, app-store, distribution, enterprise

Is there a way to distribute my free iPhone app along with my hardware to the customer without submitting it to the AppStore. I want my app to be distributed from my internally controlled 
web-server which will authenticate the user crentials before login.

(Also, my customer limit is much more than 100, so cannot take developer license in this case)

Can I use enterprise license in this situation as I am NOT charging anything from the customer. I just want the user of my hardware to control it through his iPhone [using my free application.]

Please suggest which license to choose in this case. (My main concern is not to use APPSTORE for distribution purpose).

Comment: You probably would sign up for the [Enterprise Development Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/), distribute the phone with your Provisioning Profile, and include the App. However, I am not sure about the licensing, if you are allowed to do this to distribute apps outside your own organization. Apple *really* wants you using the AppStore as much as possible.

Comment: i am looking for a way to distribute it to my customers who are external to my organization. since the application is free, and i donot earn any revenue from this app, so can we use enterprise development program in this case?

Comment: I don't think so, I *believe* the enterprise development is for in-house users only, but you might want to get that clarified.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no legal solution to your problem. With an enterprise solution you can deploy your app to any iOS device in the world, but in the license agreement Apple states that this should be done only on devices of your employees.

> (d) Distribute Provisioning Profiles only to Your Employees and only
>   in conjunction with Your Internal Use Applications for the purpose of
>   developing and testing Your Internal Use Applications;
>
> (e) Distribute Provisioning Profiles only to Your Employees in
>   conjunction with Your deployment of Your Internal Use Applications on
>   Deployment Devices for internal use by Your Employees; and
>
> (f) Allow Your Customers to use Your Internal Use Applications, but
>   only (i) on Your physical premises, or (ii) in other locations,
>   provided all such use is under the direct supervision and physical
>   control of Your Employees (e.g., a sales presentation to a Customer).

So I think the best way for you to go is through the app store itself.

Comment: am i eligible for enterprise profile?

Comment: Apple says "You must be a company or organization with a DUNS number to apply." That's why I think App store is the best option for you.

Comment: Dear Vin, can you please provide me with the link from where you took points (d) (e) and (f)

Comment: DearVin, i am a part of a company with more than 500 employees, so getting DUNS will not be an issue

Comment: Actually the restriction of having 500 employees was lifted long ago by Apple. The restriction doesn't apply for getting a DUNS number.

Comment: Dear Vin, can you please provide me with the link from where you took points (d) (e) and (f)

Comment: This was taken from enterprise developer license agreement. You can only see it when you are registered for enterprise license.

Comment: is it possible if you can please share this document (if it is legal) i hold a developer license. can you email me?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the document with you due to legal restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look into Apple's [B2B sales program](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/volume/). It lets you sell your app to specific customers rather than to the public.

Comment: B2B is only available in the US. I would like to use it and I can't.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Out of curiosity, if the app is free and it's tied to your hardware, why don't you want to use the app store?

Comment: but for that also, i guess we need to submit app on Appstore. Please correct me if  i am wrong.

Comment: You would have to submit it to Apple, yes, but it wouldn't appear on the public app store. I think it would have to cost something, though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible with Apple without jailbreak.

Did you consider to distribute it via Android?

Edit: Did you consider to do a web-app?

Comment: i want to deploy it on iPhone/iPad

Comment: to start with, we planned iphone app, later if things donot work out, then we would consider web-app

Answer (score 0):

No.  You must use Apple's App store.  For over 99 customers (who are not employees) the only way to distribute native apps to users of stock iOS devices is via Apple's App store, which requires submitting the app to Apple for approval.

An Enterprise enrollment is only useful if you are a D&B rated corporation planning on distributing the app strictly to only employees (not customers) of your corporation.

Apple has in the past approved apps that required special hardware to operate.  You may need to send them sample hardware, a video of the sample hardware being operated, or a remote login to your custom hardware.  But YMMV.

There is no other solution for distributing native apps for stock iOS devices.  But you can distribute web apps and web clipping (which can run in Safari) from your web site.